# rabbitmq error when connect

Tags: php, queue, message-queue, rabbitmq

i got this error when i try to connect using php-amqp:
Fatal error: Class 'AMQPConnection' not found in

```
$credentials =array('host' => 'localhost','port' => 5672);
$cnn = new AMQPConnection($credentials);
$cnn->connect();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the [AMQP PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/amqp) installed.  That PECL extension is *not* a default part of PHP, so you'll need to compile and install it using the `pecl` tool.

Comment: Your link is broken, could you please edit and give a more detailed explanation of how you can download this extension?

Comment: Wow, they've completely nuked *all* of the documentation for that extension.  Without documentation, I'd be really hesitant to actually advise anyone to use that extension at this point.  There are numerous pure-PHP AMQP and STOMP libraries now, and anyone reading this old question should use one of those instead of the PECL extension.