# PHP Fatal error: Class 'AMQPConnection' not found

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424419/rabbitmq-error-when-connect). It suggests that AMQP PECL extension is not installed. However, I have successfully installed both RabbitMQ as well as built PECL AMQP extension. The following is the output of the phpinfo().

[image: phpinfo() output displaying AMQP extension configurations]

You can clearly see, AMQP is loaded correctly. However, when I try to establish a connection, it says **PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AMQPConnection' not found**. Below is the code.

```
$connection = new AMQPConnection();
```

And here is the output.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ php repos/default/test.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AMQPConnection' not found in /home/user/repos/default/test.php on line 5
```

Why this might happen? Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the CLI installation uses a different php.ini file than the web/Apache module and you need to add the extension to the CLI php.ini file as well. Where exactly that is depends on your platform.

Comment: On debian/ubuntu: `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` is for cli and `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` is for sapi.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you! I didn't know client and Apache php module have different config files. That solved everything. Aaa, I am so happy!

Comment: I m confused.I have /etc/php5/cli/php.ini in debian, Please clarify  now should I replace php.ini with php-cli.ini OR should install php-cli.ini