# Installing RabbitMQ PHP: Fatal error: Class 'AMQPConnection' not found

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I've already installed the RabbitMQ on my server and everything is working fine with it. I already tried to send and receive queued messages with a Java client and everything went perfect.

Now I need to install a PHP RabbitMQ client because I want to communicate a Java program with a PHP webpage, but this time I'm not beign so lucky.

I already followed the steps of the [official webpage for this installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqp.installation.php), specifically these steps:

```
# Download the rabbitmq-c library
hg clone http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-c/rev/3c549bb09c16 rabbitmq-c
cd rabbitmq-c
# Add the codegen requirement
hg clone http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-codegen/rev/f8b34141e6cb codegen
# Configure, compile and install
autoreconf -i && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

And actually on the console I can see that it was "installed" without any problems. But when I try to open any AMQP Connection I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'AMQPConnection' not found
```

Actually if I use the phpinfo(); command I can't see anything related to an AMQP module (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199435/php-fatal-error-class-amqpconnection-not-found) question). So I think that it may be a problem with the installation but I tried reinstalling it two times and it keeps saying that everything went well.

Have anyone crossed with this problem too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it..

The module wasn't being loaded in the right **php.ini** file. Just added `extension=amqp.so` at the end of the right **php.ini** file and restarted Apache.

Comment: It depends on your php installation, version, web server, etc