# Rabbitmq not working

Tags: php, heroku, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ for creating background worker process. On local it is running properly. My messages get pushed in queue and delivered successfully. But on Heroku It is not working. On Heroku I have installed the free version of RabbitMQ and I am using amqplib in my project.
It shows 
Error: Class 'PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection' not found

This is my code in send.php

```
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('wDvw6ei3PtyC4RXJa@skinny-woundwort-2.bigwig.lshift.net', 10356, '3cFKGbiB', 'HopwJjMQebyVRB');
        $channel = $connection->channel();
        $channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);
        $msg = new AMQPMessage('Hello World!');
        $channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');
        echo " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'\n";
        $channel->close();
        $connection->close();
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Class 'AMQPConnection' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199435/php-fatal-error-class-amqpconnection-not-found) - and perhaps also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280879/installing-rabbitmq-php-fatal-error-class-amqpconnection-not-found