# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) with RabbitMQ

Tags: iphone, rabbitmq

I am using `RabbitMQ` with `AMQP classes`. I am trying to open connection with `AMQP` with

```
AMQPConnection *t=[[AMQPConnection alloc]init];
[t connectToHost:@"localhost" onPort:5672];
[t release];
```

But I am getting this kind of error after using this code. I have downloaded `AMQP` classes from [here](https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AMQPConnection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HomePageController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks.

**Solution:**

I got the solution for above. **I have added my all .m files of AMQP classes to compiler source and its worked for me.**

Comment: possible dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199435/php-fatal-error-class-amqpconnection-not-found

Comment: Thanks rishi, I have tested rabbitmq example from command line i am getting response as well but when i try to integrate with iPhone app it give me error.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted, so that the question is closed.